# IFrame real location

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to make page with navigation and content in IFrame.
Now, there authorization process in content(IFrame) part, so after some steps it will move trough some pages, an the thing is that at that point I can't just set its src='next_page' because now I need some additional params that was appended in url in this auth process.

I need to get those params from main page. So i found that **iframe.location.href** contains real url and I could just take that extra params from it.

Only problem is that this **location** is protected in javascript.

How can I do this, if there is some other way it's still good, as log as I can accomplish my goal. Like, is it possible to inject javascript code in iframe and execute it, and somehow call external function?
I need real current location of

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as the page hosting it?

Comment: Yes, it is the same page, targeting same domain. For test it is on localhost/iframe_content.html
localhost/navigation.html

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it was some config or something, it work on same domain.